# how to get selected item from a combo box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple dynamic (combo-box) drop-down list and I want to get the value of all the selected items from different list on a single variable on click of each list

```
function createList(arrunique,arrayout){
        for (i=0 ; i < arrayout[0].length ; i++){
        var divId = i;          
        $('#tb').append('<select class="list" onclick="getChecked()" name="combo" id="'+divId+'"></select>');
        var select = document.getElementById(divId);
        select.options[select.options.length] = new Option("Select "+ arrunique[i][0]);
        for (j=1 ; j < arrunique[i].length ; j++){
            select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(arrunique[i][j]);
          }
         }
        }

        function getChecked(){              
            var elm = document.getElementByName("combo");
            alert(elm.options[elm.selectedIndex].value);
        }
```

please suggest me how can i get the value of these selected items 
how can i get the values of these selected items
please suggest me how can i get the value of these selected items 
how can i get the values of these selected items

Comment: I'll suggest to create a jsfiddle.

Comment: try to use jquery and put ur code in jsfiddle, so one can see and give u solution in a short time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you using jQuery? Try this one :

```
function getChecked(){
    alert($('select[name="combo"]').find(":selected").text());
}
```

**Update**

If you want to get the value with dynamically tag, just put a parameter.

```
function getChecked(element){
    alert($('select[name="' + element + '"]').find(":selected").text());
}
```

To call :

`getChecked('combo')`

`getChecked('combo_2')`

`getChecked('combo_3')` ...

Comment: $('select[name="combo"]:selected') for shorthand

Comment: if i want individual checked item in saprate varibale then how can i get the value

Comment: @NavKumar Do you mean 'separate' is dynamically tag's name? Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jsfiddle doing what you need http://jsfiddle.net/krasimir/bWfEd/5/
It creates dropdowns based on predefined array and objects. It attaches an event for every change event. Later you could go through every of the select elements and get its value:

JS

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
var selects = [];

var buildDropdowns = function(dropdowns) {
    for(var i=0; dropdown=dropdowns[i]; i++) {
        var select = document.createElement("SELECT");
        for(var j=0; option=dropdown[j]; j++) {
            var o = new Option(option.label, option.value);
            select.options[select.options.length] = o;
        }
        wrapper.appendChild(select);
        select.addEventListener("change", getValues);
        selects.push(select);
    }
}
var getValues = function() {
    var values = [];
    for(var i=0; select=selects[i]; i++) {
        values.push(select.value);
    }
    alert(values);
}

buildDropdowns([
    [
        { value: 1, label: "Option1"},
        { value: 2, label: "Option2"},
        { value: 3, label: "Option3"},
        { value: 4, label: "Option4"}
    ],
    [
        { value: 1, label: "Option1"},
        { value: 2, label: "Option2"},
        { value: 3, label: "Option3"},
        { value: 4, label: "Option4"}
    ],
    [
        { value: 1, label: "Option1"},
        { value: 2, label: "Option2"},
        { value: 3, label: "Option3"},
        { value: 4, label: "Option4"}
    ]
]);
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

notice that *getValues* actually has an access to every of the dropdows so you can do whatever you need with the selected values.

Answer (score 0):

I think in Aldi's answer is very close, but not quite.

You have to get :selected of option element, not select. Which means the selector should be: `$('select[name="' + element + '"] option:selected').text()`

Working example using newest legacy jQuery:

HTML:

```
<select name="testSelect">
    <option value="1">Test1</option>
    <option value="2">Test2</option>
    <option value="3">Test3</option>
    <option value="4">Test4</option>
    <option value="5">Test5</option>
</select>

<div class="log"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
function getChecked(element){
    $('.log').append('<br/>Selected element: ' + $('select[name="' + element + '"] option:selected').text());
}

$('select').on('change', function() {
    getChecked($(this).prop('name'));
});
```

Live demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/daJzE/2/